# Using a plain POST form within an Angular 2 template results in: "Template parse errors: No provider for ControlContainer"

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I would like to have a plain html form (that does a POST without relying on javascript) within a angular 2 template.

Having the following plain POST form:

```html
<form action="connect/facebook" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="public_profile,email"/>
  <button type="submit">Connect to FB</button>
</form>
```

within the html template results in the following error:

```html
 Template parse errors: No provider for ControlContainer ("
    <h2 class="text-xs-center">{{'SIGNIN_FORM.TITLE' | translate}}</h2>

    [ERROR ->]<form action="connect/facebook" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="pub"): SigninComponent@6:8 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
 Error: Template parse errors: No provider for ControlContainer ("
   <h2 class="text-xs-center">{{'SIGNIN_FORM.TITLE' | translate}}</h2>

   [ERROR ->]<form action="connect/facebook" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="pub"): SigninComponent@6:8
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:20619:19)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:42414:51)
    at http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:42337:83
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:42337:47)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:60992:29)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:60885:44)
    at http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:61240:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:61025:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js:60925:48)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you include FormsModule in your application module?

Comment: No. Do I need that for plain "document" forms that don't rely on js?

Comment: @ulou, Adding `FormsModule` to my app's imports allows the form to be displayed but the form submission does not result in a **POST** being issued...

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea in an single page application. What do you want or need that? This causes your entire app to reload.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I need that in order to open a facebook signin page (see spring social).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `ngNoForm` to get the native behavior:

```
<form ngNoForm action="connect/facebook" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again Günter!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `FormsModule` provider is missing in your application module, try add:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

to your `@NgModule`, don't forget to add it to `imports` also.

Comment: Thanks ulou: See my comment above about the form not issuing the POST request.